# How do I put an file input element in the preference pane of a Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to let the user upload an image (to the folder of the addon) in the preferences window of my addon.

This is my current `prefpane`:

```
<prefpane id="tpt-pane" label="Settings">
  <preferences>
    <preference id="pref_upload" name="addonname.upload" type="file"/>
  </preferences>

  <hbox align="center">
    <label control="upload" value="The file: "/>
    <input type="file" preference="pref_upload" id="upload" />
  </hbox>
</prefpane>
```

Is there any way I can do this (with a workaround)?

Comment: Can you upload your code ti github and link me. It looks like you are doing xul pref pane. Would you like to try inline options? Its super easy to make these file dialogs etc.

Comment: I don't have much more than this. I don't do anything with the image yet.

Comment: What do you want to do with image after selected?

Comment: I want to change the `src` of an image on a site with the local url of the image I just uploaded.

Comment: How about i give you the image path? Then you can make nsIFile out of it and upload or do whatever.

Comment: Yes I already thought about that, but I wanted it to be more user-friendly, because the image is often made by the user itself and not uploaded to a server on beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here is a complete addon example that shows you to do it:

[GitHub :: Noitidart / PortableTester](https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/tree/inline-options)

Click on the XPI there and download it, and then drag it onto firefox to install it. OR just use [AMO :: GitHub Extension Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/) to install the extension from the repo link above

So what I did was create a `options.xul` file. And in `install.rdf` make sure you haven't set `<em:optionsType>` to anything.

Then the contents of `options.xul` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<vbox xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <setting title="Image Upload" type="file" pref="extensions.PortableTester@jetpack.image_upload" oninputchanged="alert('path of image is:' + this.value + '\nyou can access this image from your addon or anywhere else by getting the pref value so like this:\n`Services.prefs.getCharPref(\'extensions.PortableTester@jetpack.image_upload\') == `' + Services.prefs.getCharPref('extensions.PortableTester@jetpack.image_upload'))">
        Select image to upload
    </setting>
</vbox>
```

So after installing the addon go to addons panel. Ctlr shift A.
[image]

then click on options. You will see this:
[image]

now click browse and pick a file, and then it will prompt you, i use the `oninputchanged` attribute seen in `options.xul` above, to alert the value. It saves the path of the image to a preferenced called `extensions.PortableTester@jetpack.image_upload` you can change this to whatever name you want but keep the `extensions.` prefix.

You can now access the value in the `oninputchanged` command with `this.value` or from anywhere, any addon, or anyplace, with `Services.prefs.getCharPref('extensions.PortableTester@jetpack.image_upload')`